# How to store additional user info when using firebase authentication in Ionic / Angular app?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Below I am using firebase authentication to sign users up to my Ionic / Angular app:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

name: string = '';
email: string = '';
password: string = '';
isMechanic: boolean = false;

signup() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then((data) => {    
        let newUser: firebase.User = data.user;
        newUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.name,
          photoURL: ''
        }).then(() => {
        }).catch((err) => {
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
      });
  }
```

I am able to successfully sign users up using this.

However, I want to store the value of `isMechanic` as part of the `User`, so I can identify if they are a mechanic or not.

Can someone please tell me how this is done in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

The `Additional User Info` that you're referring to is called `Metadata`

If you check out the official JavaScript SDK for Firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

You'll find that the `firebase.user` contains a property called `metadata`

Unfortunately - they don't have the ability to store anything in that object - it's only the creationTime and lastSigninTime. (infact Firebase doesn't provides any mechanism to store user side information in the user table)

I would suggest an `architecturally better approach` to create another side-table called `user-metadata` having `user-id as a foreign key` and it's corresponding information. 
once you receive the user id after authentication - you can simply add an entry to the user-metadata table with the userid and `isMechanic` value.

For fetching back the results - you can simply perform a join operation between firebase user table and user-metadata table and give back the results.

hope that's a good starting point for your work.

Answer (score 0):

- add some data to the user using `updateProfile`
- create an entry in a new collection `users`
- use the `uid` for the user you just created
- create the new entry

```
export const doCreateAccount = (
  accountInfo: any
): Promise<boolean | string> => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      // handle the user creation for authentication
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        accountInfo.email,
        accountInfo.password
      );

      await auth?.currentUser?.updateProfile({
        displayName: accountInfo.firstName + " " + accountInfo.lastName,
      });

      let usersRef = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid);

      let accountCreated = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

      let newUserData = {
        ...accountInfo,
        activationEmailSent: { wasSent: true, accountCreated },
      };

      // save the user profile information

      delete newUserData["password"];
      delete newUserData["password2"];
      await usersRef.set(newUserData);

      resolve(true);
    } catch ({ message }) {
      reject(message);
    }
  });
};
```